# I have error on unity its say the error is on the first line of game.gradle

Tags: gradle

CommandInvokationFailure: Gradle build failed.

C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK\bin\java.exe -classpath "C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\Tools\gradle\lib\gradle-launcher-7.2.jar" org.gradle.launcher.GradleMain "-Dorg.gradle.jvmargs=-Xmx128000m" "bundleRelease"

Environment Variables:

RlsSvcPort = 22112

USERDOMAIN = YARON

ProgramFiles = C:\Program Files

TMP = C:\Users\yaron\AppData\Local\Temp

BURST_ANDROID_MIN_API_LEVEL = 22

PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE = AMD64

PROCESSOR_REVISION = 9a03

ACSvcPort = 17532

OS = Windows_NT

CHROME_CRASHPAD_PIPE_NAME = \.\pipe\crashpad_24412_GOFYHXNGOFGSAQCA

PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER = Intel64 Family 6 Model 154 Stepping 3, GenuineIntel

AMPLITUDE_API_KEY = 28f3cae0b33b8b3702120c9ed1a935aa

USERPROFILE = C:\Users\yaron

JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\OpenJDK

CommonProgramFiles = C:\Program Files\Common Files

DriverData = C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\DriverData

ComSpec = C:\WINDOWS\system32\cmd.exe

LAUNCH_DARKLY_CLIENT_TOKEN = 60a7e30fafc7e60e33446283

ACSetupSvcPort = 23210

ANDROID_NDK_ROOT = C:\Program Files\Unity\Hub\Editor\2022.3.4f1\Editor\Data\PlaybackEngines\AndroidPlayer\NDK

SystemRoot = C:\WINDOWS

HEAP_CLIENT_TOKEN = 1717415662

PSModulePath = C:\Program Files\WindowsPowerShell\Modules;C:\WINDOWS\system32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\Modules

NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS = 20

AMPLITUDE_API_KEY_STAGING = 83ee04fccc67e4fcc7dd527c4c6f1e21

WOOTRIC_CLIENT_TOKEN = NPS-aa8be4c3

JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS = -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

DEBUG_ENV_VAR = UnityHub

ProgramW6432 = C:\Program Files

FPS_BROWSER_APP_PROFILE_STRING = Internet Explorer

HOMEDRIVE = C:

TEMP = C:\Users\yaron\AppData\Local\Temp

Path = C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Program Files\Razer Chroma SDK\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\Razer\ChromaBroadcast\bin;C:\Program Files\Razer\ChromaBroadcast\bin;C:\Windows\system32;C:\Windows;C:\Windows\System32\Wbem;C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\Windows\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files (x86)\NVIDIA Corporation\PhysX\Common;C:\Program Files\NVIDIA Corporation\NVIDIA NvDLISR;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0;C:\WINDOWS\System32\OpenSSH;C:\Program Files\Docker\Docker\resources\bin;C:\WINDOWS\system32\config\systemprofile\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Program Files\dotnet;C:\Users\yaron\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311\Scripts;C:\Users\yaron\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python311;C:\Users\yaron\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\Users\yaron.dotnet\tools

EFC_12304 = 1

USERNAME = yaron

COMPUTERNAME = YARON

PATHEXT = .COM;.EXE;.BAT;.CMD;.VBS;.VBE;.JS;.JSE;.WSF;.WSH;.MSC

SystemDrive = C:

ALLUSERSPROFILE = C:\ProgramData

SENTRY_ACCESS_TOKEN = 3df78d9e53f8456aa90fbae044ce1a6261421ab1d0014674bc2e933477289017

HEAP_CLIENT_TOKEN_STAGING = 3786794399

FPS_BROWSER_USER_PROFILE_STRING = Default

windir = C:\WINDOWS

ZES_ENABLE_SYSMAN = 1

PUBLIC = C:\Users\Public

CommonProgramFiles(x86) = C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files

APPDATA = C:\Users\yaron\AppData\Roaming

OneDrive = C:\Users\yaron\OneDrive

PROCESSOR_LEVEL = 6

CommonProgramW6432 = C:\Program Files\Common Files

ProgramFiles(x86) = C:\Program Files (x86)

NVIDIAWHITELISTED = 0x01

SESSIONNAME = Console

LOGONSERVER = \YARON

LOCALAPPDATA = C:\Users\yaron\AppData\Local

HOMEPATH = \Users\yaron

LAUNCH_DARKLY_CLIENT_TOKEN_STAGING = 60a7e30fafc7e60e33446282

SHIM_MCCOMPAT = 0x810000001

USERDOMAIN_ROAMINGPROFILE = YARON

ProgramData = C:\ProgramData

ORIGINAL_XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP = undefined

stderr[

Picked up JAVA_TOOL_OPTIONS: -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

- Where:

Build file 'C:\Users\yaron\guess the picture\Library\Bee\Android\Prj\IL2CPP\Gradle\launcher\build.gradle' line: 1

- What went wrong:

A problem occurred evaluating project ':launcher'.

> Failed to apply plugin 'com.android.internal.application'.

> Could not create plugin of type 'AppPlugin'.

```
  > Could not generate a decorated class for type AppPlugin.

     > com/google/protobuf/ProtocolMessageEnum
```

- Try:

Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output. Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

BUILD FAILED in 874ms

]

stdout[

]

exit code: 1

UnityEditor.Android.Command.WaitForProgramToRun (UnityEditor.Utils.Program p, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at :0)

UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo psi, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at :0)

UnityEditor.Android.Command.Run (System.String command, System.String args, System.String workingdir, UnityEditor.Android.Command+WaitingForProcessToExit waitingForProcessToExit, System.String errorMsg) (at :0)

UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools.RunJava (System.String args, System.String workingdir, System.Action`1[T] progress, System.String error) (at :0)

UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at :0)

Rethrow as GradleInvokationException: Gradle build failed

UnityEditor.Android.GradleWrapper.Run (UnityEditor.Android.AndroidJavaTools javaTools, Unity.Android.Gradle.AndroidGradle androidGradle, System.String workingdir, System.String task, System.Action`1[T] progress) (at :0)

UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.Tasks.BuildGradleProject.Execute (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at :0)

UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessRunner.RunAllTasks (UnityEditor.Android.PostProcessor.PostProcessorContext context) (at :0)

UnityEngine.GUIUtility:ProcessEvent(Int32, IntPtr, Boolean&)

I DONT KNOW WHAT IS THIS

Comment: Please read [ask] and format your question, make use of code-formatting. Questions that are easy to read and don't overloaded with information are easier to answer.